# Trying to make a random Color selector and i don't know what is wrong

Tags: python

I have made a dictionary and a list like so:

```
Colours = {'Aqua': 4, 'Fuschia': 4, 'Purple': 4, 'Maroon': 4, 'Red': 4, 
'Blue': 4, 'Green': 4, 'Black': 4, 'Yellow': 4,  'Grey': 4}
Colours_list = ["Aqua", "Fuschia", "Purple", "Maroon", "Red", "Blue", 
"Green", "Black", "Yellow", "Grey"]
```

And then I select a random color from the list and then but it into the dictionary:

```
Colour = random.choice(Colours_list)
```

I want to be able to reduce the number a color has been given without it returning to its original value of 4 after it has been picked.
As after I redo a loop it returns the color to 4 even if it has been picked before.

This is what I am using to reduce the number once it has been picked:

```
Number = Colours[Colour]
Number -=1
Colours[Colour] = Number
if Number == 0:
    del Colours[Colour]
```

Comment: Your code works. Can you show us a minimal example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: if I add a for [Variable], [Variable] in Colors Statement after the if every time I run it, the for statement will tell me that the previous color has 4 again

Comment: I would add an image but I don't have enough rep

Comment: Instead of adding an image, create a demonstration that shows the issue.

Comment: Ok so if I have the color Aqua for example and is picked from the List.  It takes Aqua and puts it into Colours[Colour] and returns 4. It then takes 1 away and then assigns 3 back to Aqua. So if i Run the code again and Red is picked Red has a value of 3 and Aqua returns to 4. Hope this helps

Comment: You mean that the values go back to 4 *between restarts*? So you are starting your Python code *anew* and then it starts at 4 again? If so, then yes, that is normal behaviour. You need to instead write your dictionary to a file and read it next time you run the program.

Comment: Its inside a while loop and goes through the code again. How would I write a dictionary file?

Comment: You can search google for *python save dictionary to file* and go from there?

Comment: FWIW, there's an unrelated problem with the logic in the existing code in your question: when you delete an entry from `Colours` you also need to update `Colours_list`. In Python 3, you can simply set `Colours_list` to [`Colours.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) instead of the initialization of  `Colours_list` you're currently using, the Python 2.7 equivalent is [`Colours.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys); in earlier versions you need to do `Colours_list = Colours.keys()` each time you `del` a colour.

Comment: (cont) Alternatively, in pre 2.7 versions you can do `Colours_list.remove(Colour)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re-run the program, the dictionary is reinitialised. The dictionary Colours is setup as `Colours = {'Aqua': 4, 'Fuschia': 4, 'Purple': 4, 'Maroon': 4, 'Red': 4, Blue': 4, 'Green': 4, 'Black': 4, 'Yellow': 4,  'Grey': 4}` whenever you re-run the code. For looking at how to save and reuse dictionaries, I recommend looking at the Shelve or Pickle Modules.